unable to download the data of era5 using new beta CDS
I am unable to download data from era5 using cdsapi code in python.
it might be due to incorrect update of my cdsapi but not sure.
i have shared my code and the error messages .....please guide if anyone know its rectification.
import cdsapi

dataset = "reanalysis-era5-single-levels"
request = {
    'product_type': ['reanalysis'],
    'variable': ['10m_u_component_of_wind', '10m_v_component_of_wind'],
    'year': ['2024'],
    'month': ['05'],
    'day': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14',       '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
    'time': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00',   '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00',   '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
    'data_format': 'netcdf',
    'download_format': 'unarchived',
    'area': [38, 61, 23, 81]
}

client = cdsapi.Client()
client.retrieve(dataset, request).download()

With above code, i get below erroe message.
In my thought, it is might because of problems in syntax of new cdsapi key
2024-08-05 17:14:42,529 INFO Sending request to https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/api/resources/reanalysis-era5-single-levels
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\SHAHID HUSSAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\cdsapi\\api.py", line 442, in \_api
result.raise_for_status()
File "C:\\Users\\SHAHID HUSSAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\requests\\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/api/resources/reanalysis-era5-single-levels

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\\Year 2024\\may_uvwind10m.py", line 17, in \<module\>
client.retrieve(dataset, request).download()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\SHAHID HUSSAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\cdsapi\\api.py", line 364, in retrieve
result = self.\_api("%s/resources/%s" % (self.url, name), request, "POST")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\SHAHID HUSSAIN\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\cdsapi\\api.py", line 464, in \_api
raise Exception(error)
Exception: Not Found


i need to update to beta cds myself, I'll try it out later and report back

Be sure to install cdsapi version >= 0.7.0 (latest is 0.7.3 at the moment).  The cdsapi module actually imports cads_api_client and weirdly calls it a legacy client, but in fact the beta CDS service has very different URLs and the JSON format is just different enough to be incompatible.  Try pip install --upgrade 'cdsapi>=0.7.0'

Had the same issue, I needed to update the .cdsapi file as the url and key had changed for some reason.
https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/how-to-api
Currently it says the file should contain:
url: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api
key: db7a9f5c-2064-4a6e-9b4f-d220a04a128e
